# What if two players are eligible for the Express bonus?

Tags: scoring, ticket-to-ride-europe

The longest path for Adam are ten trains while Bella and Celia both has a longest path of fifteen trains, i.e both Bella and Celia has the longest path and thus are eligible for the Express Bonus/European Express.

Are the express bonus points divided between Bella and Celia, do they both receive the entire bonus of ten points, or is the express bonus skipped?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [rules](https://cdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/te_rules_2015_en.pdf), p7:

> If several players are tied for the longest path, they each receive the 10 point bonus from the European Express card.